# Order Wordpress-attributes by global/backend order (orderby)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a function, where all available colors (attributes/terms) gets attached to each product - on the category-page (product-listing). The code below works, however, the frontend-order is not identical with the backend-order. I really can't figure out, how I'm suppose to get the attributes sorted accordingly. Have tried changing `menu_order` to `term_order` aswell. This dosen't work either.

```
function ea_display_color_swatches_on_category() {
    $html_swatch = '<div class="swatches-wrapper">';

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pa_farve', array( 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $hex_color = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'pa_farve_swatches_id_color', true );

        $html_swatch .= '<a class="swatch-color-category tooltips"
            title="' . $term->name . '"
            style="background:' . $hex_color . '" ></a>';
    }

    // end color-swatches-wrapper
    $html_swatch .= '</div>';

    echo $html_swatch;


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'ea_display_color_swatches_on_category' );
```

[image]

[image]

[Source](https://www.ejstruplys.dk/product-category/stearinlys/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with term_id? WordPress use to sort by creation date.